# Export data set from my good data project using Java SDK

Tags: java, gooddata

I would like to export all data from my data set in my good data project by means of the official Java SDK. Unfortunately, I can see that the reports only can be exported through this SDK.

This is the reason I would like to ask if there is any way how to do so?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoodData platform does not support direct export of datasets, therefore it is also not part of any SDK. 
You can build report that will reflect full dataset and export it.